# How do I correctly pass CMake list (semicolon-sep) of flags to set_target_properties?

Tags: cmake

CMake lists are essentially just semicolon-separated strings, but if you pass such a variable to a command, it does get expanded into multiple arguments - for example,

```
set(FLAGS f1 f2 f3)
# now FLAGS == 'f1;f2;f3'
add_custom_command(
  ...
  COMMAND my_cmd ${FLAGS}
  ...
)
```

will correctly call `my_cmd f1 f2 f3`.

Now if I do this with

```
set_target_properties(
  myTarget PROPERTIES
  LINK_FLAGS  "${LD_FLAGS}"
)
```

the expansion does not occur, and I end up with a single `LD_FLAG` that contains semicolons -- useless, instead of expanding it into a space-separated string.

Is there any way to make it so that when I pass a list to the LINK_FLAGS property (or any property that is), it gets expanded into multiple arguments rather than just one?

Answer (score 32):

I don't think `set_target_properties` can do the expansion automatically, but you can use `string (REPLACE ...)` to expand a list into a space separated string:

```
string (REPLACE ";" " " LD_FLAGS_STR "${LD_FLAGS}")
set_target_properties(
  myTarget PROPERTIES
  LINK_FLAGS  "${LD_FLAGS_STR}"
)
```

Comment: Is this really the best way?  Why was CMake designed to use a list format that is not compatible with its own `set_target_properties` command?

Comment: The main problem with this technique in general is that if any of the flags contain spaces, they will cause problems.  There will need to be some escaping applied to preserve spaces in arguments if it is possible (e.g. if an externally supplied filename is included, which may contain spaces).

Comment: B+++T. It doesn't work. `string (REPLACE ";" " " DEST ${SRC})` replaces the semicolon with... an empty string. Only this works: `foreach(OPT ${LD_FLAGS})        set(LINK_FLAGS "${LINK_FLAGS} ${OPT}")
      endforeach()`. It would be really funny, unless this c+++p weren't the most popular build tool today.

Comment: @Ethouris `string (REPLACE ";" " " DEST "${SRC}")` works; you seem to have missed the quotes around the last argument. Perhaps all those +s were in the way?

Comment: Right. This `${SRC}` contained `;` inside and in this form it has expanded itself inside the call (so the replacement didn't even get a chance to work). At least it's worth to remember that cmake repeats the same stupid mistake as bash and perl do.

Comment: What happens if an individual argument contains ';'? Then the string replacement would need to work with (if at all) with cmake's internal escape mechanism. It's a messy solution. In contrast, Ethouris's solution seems much cleaner to me.

Answer (score 22):

For using a cmake List as list, use

```
${LD_FLAG}
```

For using a cmake list as string, (i.e. list items are separated with ';'), use

```
"${LD_FLAG}"
```

So in your case, just remove "" should be sufficient.

Comment: Strange, but this one didn't work for me, version 3.9 :( `set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.`

Comment: @Andry What's it show if you insert "MESSAGE("${LD_FLAG}")" in front of it?

Comment: @Ding-Yi Chen I didn't use that. Instead i have been using set of `LINK_FLAGS_*` variables. The idea here is try to avoid using the `list as string` at all. Instead do use something like `set(PROP_LIST "${PROP_LIST} ...")` and `set_target_properties(... LINK_FLAGS_* "${PROP_LIST}")`. The attemp to use `PROP_LIST` as the list will ruin the `set_target_properties`.

Answer (score 9):

The `set_property` command is designed for this

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_property.html

```
set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS foo bar)
```

Comment: Steveire - I mistakenly thought it wasn't in 2.8.11, because I tried to change `set_target_properties(foo ...)` to `set_properties(TARGET foo ...)`. But now I see that there is a difference in pluralization of the command names (plural vs singular). The correct name is `set_property` (ends in `y`).

Comment: Yes, you can use set_property() the way this answer shows, but CMake treats LINK_FLAGS as a plain string, not a list -- this means in this answer the link is passed a single argument, `foo;bar`.  It's unfortunate.  It's also interesting that there is now a `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property that is a list, but the old `COMPILE_FLAGS` is a plain string.

Answer (score 2):

I use it like strings

`set(FLAGS " f1 f2 f3")`

Note the space in the front, it allows you to concatenate other sets of flags.

For more complex projects, instead of if-elses you may also do a *double expansion* trick:

```
set(GCC_FLAGS " -Wl,--relax")
set(DIAB_FLAGS " -tPPCE500ES:cross")
set(MSVC_FLAGS " /RAINBOW_CRAP)
# ...
# ...LINUX_FLAGS, WINDOWS_FLAGS, etc...


set_target_properties(
  myTarget PROPERTIES
  LINK_FLAGS  "${${COMPILER}_FLAGS} ${${SYSTEM}_FLAGS}"
)

# COMPILER and SYSTEM is set somewhere else, in toolchain files for example
```

Answer (score 0):

```
separate_arguments(LD_FLAGS_AS_LIST  NATIVE_COMMAND  LD_FLAGS)

set_target_properties(
  myTarget PROPERTIES
  LINK_FLAGS  "${LD_FLAGS_AS_LIST}"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of CMake 3.12, you can use the `list(JOIN <list> <glue> <output variable>)` command [described here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#reading):

```
set(FLAGS f1 f2 f3)
# now FLAGS == 'f1;f2;f3'
list(JOIN FLAGS " " FLAGS) # Note: Overwrites FLAGS variable
# now FLAGS == 'f1 f2 f3'
add_custom_command(
  ...
  COMMAND my_cmd ${FLAGS}
  ...
)
```

This is a little more direct than using `string(REPLACE ...)`.

Answer (score -1):

In cmake 3.x there are a few approaches

The top level CMakeLists.txt file then looks something like this:

```
# The name of the included file could be anything,
# it doesn't have to be called CMakeLists.txt
include(foo/CMakeLists.txt)
include(bar/CMakeLists.txt)

add_executable(myApp ${myApp_SOURCES})
```

with the subdirectory files structured something like this:

```
list(APPEND myApp_SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/foo.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/foo_p.cpp
)
```

[Enhanced source file handling with target_sources()](https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/)